# like, comment for a listview feed

Tags: java, android, listview

I started to make an app with help of some online courses and I want to improve my skills also.
My app like Istagram, there is a `listView` for posts and I made a `custom_view.xml` for each row of list view. There are 3 parts inside of the custom view: userPP, userName, userPost, userComment.

But I don't know how I can add like, comment button. I mean, I want to go to user's profile page when I touch the profile picture. How can get the image's URL(which come from dataBase) or userName value when I touch it on the feed ? and also other parts on the feed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you clarify what you're asking? It sounds like you're asking a few different questions, which is confusing. Can you focus on just one?

Comment: Thanks @LarsH ! I have a list view on my `feedActivity.java` and this listview conected to dataBase (FireBase). When I open the app all posts fill this ListView. The question is that how can I get the URL when I touch a image on the listView?

Comment: Are you talking about setOnTouchListener? Example: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.widget.ListView&method=setOnTouchListener